# Typesetting a style of bibliography used a lot in mathematics literature

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

In mathematics books and articles people tend to use the following formation for their citations:[image]
while In the body of the article you see something like this: "According to [B] and [Be] blah blah blah." I want to typeset this style for my own works.

I did a search and although I'm not sure but I think this style is called *alphanum*? The problem is I could not run my code with alphnum style: Here is my code for the style *alpha* (which works)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\begin{document}
Trial \cite{Hu} and \cite{knapp}.

\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{foo}

\end{document}
```

This runs perfectly but the moment I replace the style with alphanum, although the code still compiles, the bibliography becomes non-existent and cites become replaced with [?]. Clearly my compiler doesn't recognize this style. So I have no way of checking whether the style I want is in fact alphanum. So my question is two-fold:

> Is this style *alphanum* and if not what is it? Whatever it is how can I use it?

Oh and I almost forgot to mention: I use Windows and MikTeX.

Comment: The style is called `alpha` and your example code is how to use it.

Comment: @eldering alpha does it differently though: My citation for \cite{Hu} is authored by Humphreys. So in the style I want it should be cited as [H] or [Hu]. But what happens in alpha is [Hum72].

Comment: That's a very old-fashioned style, devised when papers were typewritten and using numbers was impossible. It's not really so helpful to the reader, unless the number of citations is very small, otherwise it tends to be cumbersome as the [B] and [Be] examples show. The `alpha` style has been modelled on the habits in other fields of research (computer science, for instance) and automatically forms the labels from the list of authors. I'm not saying it is impossible to do the same with BibTeX, but it would require a large amount of work.

Comment: With biblatex+biber, that would be relatively easy to do by using a custom label format (see `\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate` in the biblatex documentation)

Comment: @PLK can you please give me an example? I tried to figure it out myself, but it is so confusing.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of doing this with biblatex. The important parts are the `\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate` and the `\DeclareFieldFormat`. The former sets the label format and the latter ensures that the extraalpha field remains numeric. Note that this is not exactly like your example output simply because of the order of the references but this should not matter as what you need is unique labels of a particular format.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@BOOK{test1,
  AUTHOR = {Bourbaki, N.},
  Title  = {Title}
}
@BOOK{test2,
  AUTHOR = {Bernard, D.},
  Title  = {Title}
}
@BOOK{test3,
  AUTHOR = {Bernard, D. and Felder, G.},
  Title  = {Title}
}
@BOOK{test4,
  AUTHOR = {Cherednik, I.},
  Title  = {Title1}
}
@BOOK{test5,
  AUTHOR = {Cherednik, I.},
  Title  = {Title2}
}
@BOOK{test6,
  AUTHOR = {Cherednik, I.},
  Title  = {Title3}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{
  \labelelement{
    \field[varwidthlist]{labelname}
  }
}
\DeclareFieldFormat{extraalpha}{#1}%
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]